# python scripting in maya

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, maya

I want to build a GUI that would help a user (who is not familiar with Maya) to just drag and drop shapes to create the model of a complex shape they want and then let Maya automatically professionally draw it for them.

I have 2 approaches but can't seem to find which of them is even possible
1- scripting inside MAYA
I can't find resources for libraries that can let me create drag and drop UIs directly in Maya
so any suggestions?
Would using PyQT be helpful?

2- creating the GUI externally on a web app or so
The problem here is what format would I export the user's sketch in that it allows Maya to read
and understand what these shapes represent and be able to draw a model?

Any resources or ideas would be helpful, please.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a book called "Practical Maya Programming with Python" that should help.  I doubt you're going to find many Maya users here, given its price.

https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/hardware-and-creative/9781849694728/copyrightpg

Comment: Adding some additional infos here. I recommend to use Pyside since it is supported by Autodesk. And there are possibilities to execute commands if you drag'n drop something into maya, even if it takes some research. And concering the second question: First you have to know what data exactly you want to use in Maya, then you can think about formats I guess.